# can't fire activity on onListItemClick in Listactivity with buttons in list?

Tags: android, button, listactivity, oncreate

can't fire activity on onListItemClick() in ListActivity with buttons in list?

if i touch the button, i could not get into the referred activity. it just stays there in that page even on click.

```
     public class Intro4 extends ListActivity{
String classes[] = {"Entertainment","TextPlay","Current-Affairs"};
public static int correct,wrong,marks;
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese= classes[position];
        try {
            Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.SVS."+cheese);
            Intent ini= new Intent(Intro4.this,ourClass);
            startActivity(ini);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          }
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Intro4.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,classes));
}}
```

Manifest is:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Intro1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Intro2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.SVS.INTRO2" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Intro3"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.SVS.INTRO3" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Intro4"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.SVS.INTRO4" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".Entertainment"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.SVS.ENTERTAINMENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name=".TextPlay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.SVS.TEXTPLAY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.SVS.MAINACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: did you receive anything in logcat? exception or any error?

Comment: try Intent ini= new Intent(Intro4.this,ourClass.class);

Comment: Are you sure click is `onListItemClick`  happening on row click. use log and check method is executing or not

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: i have also posted Manifest for yu @PratikButani-AndroidButs

Comment: hey.. i got the toast message placed in catch(classNotFound e).. But the class is present @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 0):

Here:

> String classes[] = {"Entertainment","TextPlay","Current-Affairs"};

`Current-Affairs` is not a valid java identifier. see [Using Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) for more details.

And make sure all activities `Entertainment,TextPlay,...` is declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Even after removing "Current-Affairs".. it is doing nothing.. and i have checked all acts in AndroidManifest.xml... the problem remains unsolved @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @KovuriVinay: use `Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.SVS."+cheese);
            Intent ini= new Intent(Intro4.this,ourClass);
            startActivity(ini);` lines without `try-catch` then check what happening on ListView row click

Comment: there is no error log.. n its showing in logcat: java.lang.classnotfoundexception

Comment: @KovuriVinay: post full logcat result with question

Comment: hey.. i got the toast message placed in catch(classNotFound e).. But the class is present

Comment: @KovuriVinay: you have any issue in posting log with question ?

Comment: @KovuriVinay: Great then no one i think help you he he...he he :)

Comment: Lol.!! i have taken out that log.. but i couldnt post it in here.!! i wil email it if u want that!!

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer.. in java clas..
      `Class.forname("com.svs.blabla")`
          not
     `("com.SVS.blabla")`

i.e., package name should be in lower case.